# How to hide or view stream data from inspect element and developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, web-inspector, firefox-developer-tools

I want to know how one might hide data that is being streamed on a website (such as an mp3 file) such that the resource URL cannot be viewed in inspect element or developer tools. Conversely I would also like to know how one might find the resource URL of such 'hidden' data if possible. Whether via JavaScript or otherwise.

An example website is [www.saavn.com](http://www.saavn.com) where I am unable to view any information about the streaming data in the 'Network' tab. Other resources and data are visible however. The transfer readout should have had been giving a readout in MBs instead of KBs to reflect the amount of streaming I have done. 
P.s, I can easily see all resource URL's(including the streaming mp3 file) in soundcloud.

Here is a screenshot reflecting the fact:
[image]

Comment: do you want to hide XMLHttpRequests ?

Comment: If that makes it so that the client can't see streamed data then sure! Would you say that is what they did with saavn.com? Possibly also with youtube as well?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't filter your Network panel? Why not have expiring urls or something like Widevine?

Comment: No. there's a reason I gave an example website: so that you guys could check for yourselves that the URL does not appear whatsoever in the Network tab log. Widevine is not what I am looking for as some people (including me) have it disabled in their browsers. The problem with expiring URLs is that they show up in the developer console even if they expire later.